# matlab search a matching element

Tags: matlab

I have an integer array of length 2000 elements. For ex

```
x = [2, 4, 5, 6, 5,6,7,5......];
```

Now in this array i need to find an element which occurs repeatedly. For ex I need to know how many times a number '5' has been occurred. In the above example it is three times.

Is there any way to search an matching element and returns the count in matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the number in advance?

If so, to work out how many times it appears in `x` you could do:

```
sum(x==5)
```

The `x==5` creates a vector of `[FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...]`, being `TRUE` whenever `x` is 5.

The `sum` then adds up that vector, where `FALSE` maps to 0 and `TRUE` to 1.

Comment: nnz(x==5) , numel(find(x==5)) are also valid options. IMHO they are clearer to the reader, because you are not interested in summing but in the number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

A quick way get the count is

```
sum(x == 5)
```

If you need the indicies of the matching elements:

```
find(x == 5)
```

Notice, the count is also `length(find(x == 5))`.
Standard caveats apply toward the use of `==` and floating point numbers.